# How to fetch document name from a document lib into a dropdown

Tags: web-part, document-library

This is my ascx page(Visual WebPart):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button  runat="server" ID="btn" onclick="btn_Click" Text="submit"/>
```

As you can see when I print out the item name it works but when I do

listName.Add(item.Name);

I get error. It doesn't add the items to the dropdown

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Also can I use SPQuery to show all documents and not use the where clause?

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             List<string> listName = null;

            string siteUrl = "http://site";
            using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                SPList list = spSite.RootWeb.Lists["Shared Documents"];
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />";
                query.Query =
                @"<Where>
                             <Eq>
                             <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                             <Value Type='Text'>my.docx</Value>
                             </Eq>
                             </Where>";
                SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);
                foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
                {
                    string h = item.Name.ToString();
                    Response.Write(h);
                    //listName.Add(item.Name);
                }
                DropDownList1.DataSource = listName;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippet above it looks like you're never initializing your `List<string> listName`. It's still a null object. instead of `List<string> listName = null`, do `List<string> listName = new List<string>()`;

Comment: Thanks Andrew i have reviewed the code and solved it.
Just by doing DropDownList1.items.Add(item.Name)
No need to databind also made sure to clear the DDL before adding items.
Cheer

Comment: That would work as well since the DDL automatically initializes it's own collection of ListItems, ensuring that you aren't trying to add to a null object.